# How many days should I run

Tags: running

I am 34 years old with average fitness. 
I started running since last year and usually run about 5 kms, 3 to 4 times a week. I would like to know if it seems reasonable.

Another question I have is - running on tread mail is preferable or running on roads?

Comment: How is your run going on?

Comment: It's going not so ok due to various reasons. But will be back on track soon. Thanks for asking, really like it.

Comment: keep going! I stopped running for a while but got back tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Arthur Lydiard wrote the book *Running with Lydiard* about proper running technique, building aerobic capacity and nutrition. I have started practicing according to his method and was able to run 18km without any pain. Strongly recommended for every runner.

---

To become an experienced runner may take few years, I'm doing similar amount of run plus gym 3-5 times a week.

I assume you are running not just for fun but to be able to run at least half marathon.

To protect and improve heart muscle I do recovery run on low heart rate 120bpm which is baseline for any type of runner as a recovery mode run. 30 minutes which is equal 4-5km that pace is enough. If you look any marathon training program, there is a common pattern 3-5km run during a week plus long run over weekend. An increase may be around 10% per week.

Personally I don't run longer than 6km now that's why I run on "safe mode" only to help body to adapt and reduce risk of injury. I did many mistakes like hill strikes and know more what right running technique is. The 120bpm is safe zone where you can run longer, detect many type of issues, learn how to breath and reduce heart rate. No marathoners run a long distance on higher pulse, it is just not safe.

I can recommend only what helps me: be consistent, take your time, listen your body, let it adapt, do warm up and cool down every single run.

Comment: Running slower a lot of the time is important to build your aerobic capacity and avoid injury. The biggest mistake I see is people trying to run as fast as they can every time they run.

Answer (score 4):

While it's difficult to give you exact amounts of time/distance without knowing more of your physical condition I think mikhailov mentions the most important thing possible:

Listen to your body and take it slow.

Comment: Hi and welcome to fitness.stackexchange! Not to discourage you from participating, but this would have been better as a comment to mikhailov's answer. There's an "add a comment" button below each answer (and question) for that.

Comment: Although, unfortunately, it takes 50 reputation to make comments.

Comment: It was my intention to comment but as Sean says, not enough reputation :)